# Display the selected item of a RadioButtonList in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, radiobuttonlist

I am new to ASP.NET. I am trying to display the text of a radio button in a text box when the radio button is selected. I have tried two different ways of doing it without success:

Attempt 1:

Code in my aspx file:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioList" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="selection1" Text ="One"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="selection2" Text="Two"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And then my .cs code:

```
public void displayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = radioList.SelectedValue;
    output.Text = result.Text; /* Have also tried result.ToString() */
}
```

Attempt 2:

Same aspx as above

.cs code:

```
public void displayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selection1.Checked)
    {
        output.Text = "One";
    }
}
```

The first attempt doesn't give me any errors, but doesn't display the text. The second attempt gives me Error CS0103 The name 'selection1' does not exist in the current context    1_ASPTEST.aspx

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just overlooking but I'm stumped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this too.

```
 if (radioList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
             output.Text = radioList.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
```

Hope!. It will help you